# Files app is duplicated

Tags: pantheon-files, applications, files

I have an issue with Files app being duplicated in the Applications menu:
[image]

I also noticed that the app is actually listed 4 times (!) when I try to open some file and I choose "Open with" -> "Other application":

[image]

Why is it happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I am not prepared to call this an answer. I can't duplicate your system and check. [This link](https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2019/09/how-to-edit-start-menu-items-on-elementary-os.html) may help you remove the duplicate entries in your start menu. For your open with context menu, check `defaults.list` for duplicates. It's in /usr/share/pantheon/applications. Before editing that file, back it up.

Comment: @KGIII You are right. I used App Editor and I see that I have 3 instances of Nautilus there. I marked it as "hidden". However, I wonder, where did Nautilsu come from? I didn't install it explicitly. Am I able to check that somehow? How do I remove it from the "Open with" menu?

Comment: Have you looked in the file mentioned for duplicate entries? I have no idea how you ended up with three instances, as I don't know what you've done with your computer. I can't even begin to speculate, because I've never seen it before and can't duplicate it.

Comment: @KGIII I checked the `defaults.list` file. I found 2 entries with "Files" in it: `inode/directory=io.elementary.files.desktop` and `x-scheme-handler/trash=io.elementary.files.desktop`. I'm not sure what they even mean, so I didn't touch those. I am not sure if this is the cause since I see 4 copies of Files entry in my menu, not 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 things that I did to solve this issue.
First, thanks to @KGIII I removed Applications menu entries using App Editor. I found out that the "duplicats" were actually Nautilus file manager, and not the Pantheon Files.
Then I just removed Nautilus from my system using `apt purge nautilus`.

Now, I do not have any "duplicates" in both the Applications menu and the "Open with" menu.

The only thing that I would like to learn is how Nautilus was installed on my system. I did not install it explicitly by myself, I think it had to come in as a dependency of some other package. However, am I able to know for sure how it got installed?

Comment: You can run `apt-cache rdepends --installed nautilus`, this will list the installed packages that depend on or "recommend" nautilus.

Answer (score 1):

did you install another File manager? (like Nautilus). If it is the case, the others "File" icons are the different file managers installed

Comment: No, I didn't install any other file manager

Comment: Turns out your idea was almost right. The thing is, I did not install Nautilus explicitly. It must have been installed as a dependency of some other application I guess. Am I able to see how it got installed?